# Abstract Algebra; Galois field extension and automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I am really curious...

Can $\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}}$ be written in the form $\sqrt a + \sqrt b $ with rational numbers $a$ and $b$ ?

I was thinking that we could try to brute force it by equating $\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}} = x$ and then try to work out the $a$ and $b$ ? Any thoughts ? :)

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Denesting_nested_radicals) describes a simple method to write
$$
\sqrt{a+b \sqrt{c}\ } = \sqrt{d}+\sqrt{e}
$$
with
$$
d=\frac{a + \sqrt {a^2-b^2c}}{2},
\qquad
e=\frac{a - \sqrt {a^2-b^2c}}{2}
$$
This works iff $a^2 - b^2c$ is a square.

For $\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}}$ we have $a^2 - b^2c=9$ and so
$$
\sqrt{4+\sqrt{7}} = \sqrt{\frac72}+\sqrt{\frac12}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Solve first for $8+2\sqrt 7$.